# Need for a VGA output

Tags: vga

My device must be able to show a simple diagram on a screen of an ordinary computer monitor. I've found display drivers which could do the job, but they seem to be much more sophisticated than I would need. There are some drivers from Epson, but they have hardware acceleration, sprites and much more. I only need some circles and lines. My diagram wouldn't even need to be refreshed more than every ten seconds or so.

Is there any simple display drivers?

Comment: "My device" - what device? Do you have a schematic, any code, datasheet, ..?

Comment: You know it has to display circles and lines, so you know what your minimum requirements are. Resolution, colors, ...

Comment: Display drivers for *what board / platform?* How do you envisage your connection to the VGA monitor? This question lacks sufficient information for a definitive answer, please edit it and add detail, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, VGA is pretty easy to render with an AVR microcontroller. Some examples:

- [Simple VGA/Video adapter](http://vga-avr.narod.ru/main.html) - Creating VGA/Video signals using the 8-bit AVR MCU
- [Lucid Science: AVR Video Generator](http://www.lucidscience.com/pro-vga%20video%20generator-1.aspx)
- [TSE VGA](http://www.scribd.com/doc/112309294/TSE-VGA-final-project-report-using-Arduino-and-Gameduino) - final project report using Arduino and Gameduino